# How would I clean this up?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm working with an application that utilizes the Google Weather API, right now I got some real ugly code just to populate the 3 day forecast, which looks like so (remember no laughing)

```
groupBox3.Text = set.Forecast[1].DayOfTheWeek;
label4.Text = string.Format("High {0}", set.Forecast[1].High);
label3.Text = string.Format("Low: {0}", set.Forecast[1].Low);
label11.Text = string.Format("Condition: {0}", set.Forecast[1].Condition);
pictureBox1.Load(set.Forecast[1].Icon);

groupBox4.Text = set.Forecast[2].DayOfTheWeek;
label14.Text = string.Format("High {0}", set.Forecast[2].High);
label13.Text = string.Format("Low: {0}", set.Forecast[2].Low);
label20.Text = string.Format("Condition: {0}", set.Forecast[2].Condition);
pictureBox2.Load(set.Forecast[2].Icon);

groupBox5.Text = set.Forecast[3].DayOfTheWeek;
label7.Text = string.Format("High {0}", set.Forecast[3].High);
label6.Text = string.Format("Low: {0}", set.Forecast[3].Low);
label11.Text = string.Format("Condition: {0}", set.Forecast[3].Condition);
pictureBox3.Load(set.Forecast[3].Icon);
```

I told you it was ugly. What I would like to do is have a single loop (and possible Generics) to accomplish the same task as this ugly code. I've tried a couple different ways but they always fail. The weather is being generated like so

```
WeatherSet set = WeatherService.Response(GoogleWeatherRequest.RequestData(new WeatherService("99109")));
```

And inside the variable **set** there is information for current information and 3 day forecast, but having it run like this drives me insane because it so noobish and not very efficient. So anyone got any cool & efficient way toaccomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create your own custom control ForecastView for that with groupbox, three labels and picturebox on it. Let it have a property named `Forecast` and put the logic that fills the fields inside its setter. That way the code of the form will be really clean, like

```
forecastView1.ForeCast = set.Forecast[1];
forecastView2.ForeCast = set.Forecast[2];
// etc
```

Seeing as you are already putting your field inside of the groupbox, placement shouldn't be a problem.

Also, putting it all in separate control will give you a lot of code reuse options if one day you need to present this data on another form or even in another app. Not to mention that you'll be able to change the appearance of all forecasts at once if you decide to put the pictureBox left instead of right, etc.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do with this idea, but having some issues as far as implementing it. Somehow I've got to get the data into the UC in order to populate the items in the UC. I hope that question made sense ;)

Comment: @PsychoCoder: what's wrong with adding a propery of `Forecast` type to your UC class like I suggested?

Comment: Because all that gives me is the current weather, let's see what I can come up with. I love the idea

Comment: @PsychoCoder: I meant that you'll have to place three instances of this control to display 3 different forecasts

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inefficient about your code. It's a bit sad to repeat yourself, but there's nothing really *wrong* with it.

If you want to avoid the repetition, simply put your controls in arrays so that you can do something like:

```
for (index in number of forecasts) {
   groupBox[index].Text = set.Forecast[index]....;
   hiLabel[index].Text  = ...:
   lowLabel[index].Text = ...:
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried grouping the controls or genreating the controls on the fly? That way you don't have to index into the Forecast list you can just enumerate the collection and instead of using different controls for each iteration you only have that single set to populate.

```
foreach (var item in set.Forecast.Take(3))
{
    var groupBox = new GroupBox(); // it don't if the class is actually called GroupBox...
    groupBox.Text = item.DayOfTheWeek;
    labelHigh.Text = string.Format("High {0}", item.High);
    labelLow.Text = string.Format("Low: {0}", item.Low);
    labelCondition.Text = string.Format("Condition: {0}", item.Condition);
    pictureBox.Load(item.Icon);
    groupBox.Controls.Add(labelHigh)
    ...
    this.Controls.Add(groupBox);
}
```

The above code is just to give you an idea.

And actually, there's not much that can go wrong with your code, the only thing I'm really missing is an assertation that your index isn't out of range.

Comment: You'll have to do that through code. Unless you move the controls into a user control, then the user control will act as your *grouping* and you can just create instances of that and set the properties on that user control.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended with (thanks @dyppl). For the user control idea

```
public partial class forecastView : UserControl
{    
    public forecastView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public forecastView(int x, int y, int index,WeatherSet set)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label7.Text = string.Format("High:{0}", set.Forecast[index].High);
        label8.Text = string.Format("Low: {0}", set.Forecast[index].Low);
        pictureBox3.Load(string.Format("http://www.google.com/{0}", set.Forecast[index].Icon));
        groupBox1.Text = set.Forecast[index].DayOfTheWeek;

        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

And I load them this way

```
private void LoadControls(WeatherSet set)
{
    RemoveConrols();
    //form2.Dispose();

    form = new forecastView(12, 136, 1, set);
    form1 = new forecastView(155, 136, 2, set);
    form2 = new forecastView(12, 218, 3, set);

    this.Controls.Add(form);
    this.Controls.Add(form1);
    this.Controls.Add(form2);
}
```

So thanks to all that helped me with this issue ;)